# Scraping Multiple Pages and Making a Table

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, webrequest

I've been trying to find a way to successfully scrape data from a website easily and have found that using Powershell gets me the results needed, although I can only tell how to do it one by one.

The URLs go from `www.example.com/Item/1` to `www.example.com/Item/40` and present data from a form.

I've used the commands:

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "www.example.com/Item/1"

$WebResponse.Forms.Fields
```

And the results I get are what I need, but I was wanted to be able to do it for all 40 pages and make a readable table from it.

I'm really new to anything to do with powershell so I'm assuming there's just something I'm looking over.

Answer (score 0):

Just chuck it in a loop:

```
for ( $i = 1; $i -lt 40; $i++ ) {
    $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "www.example.com/Item/$i"
    $WebResponse.Forms.Fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to write it:

```
$start = 1
$end = 40

$start..$end | select { 
   $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "www.example.com/Item/$_"
   $WebResponse.Forms.Fields
}
```